# Use a string in Python as a parameter for a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem I can't solve in Python. The question is hard to even put into words, so see the example below.

```
phoneBook = {"Joe":12, "Jason":13, "Johnny":14}

for i in range(0, len(dir(phoneBook))):
    if "__" not in dir(phoneBook)[i]:
        print(help(phoneBook.dir(phonebook)[i]) + "\n\n")
```

What I want to do is to print the help() method for each dir() entry that doesn't contain underscores. (i.e., calling dir(phoneBook) returns clear, copy, fromkeys, get, items, etc...). I want the help() method to then print each of the values that dir() returns, as seen in the for loop above. However, if I use the syntax as shown above, I get a syntax error. There are other applications of this principle, this is a quick example that I can think of off the top of my head.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well what is the syntax error. And what do you mean by `phoneBook.dir(phonebook)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working version:

```
phoneBook = {"Joe": 12, "Jason": 13, "Johnny": 14}

for method_name in dir(phoneBook):
    if "__" not in method_name:
        help(getattr(phoneBook, method_name))
```

More details:

1. You code does not have a syntax error. Not every error is a syntax error.
2. At the end you wrote `phonebook` instead of `phoneBook`.
3. `phoneBook.dir` does not mean anything.
4. `help` does the printing and returns `None`, so simply `help(...)` is enough, while `help(...) + '...'` will fail and `print(help(...))` is not needed.
5. `dir(phonebook)[i]` appears twice, `dir(phonebook)` three times. Use variables!
6. Use a better for loop! You rarely need `for i in range(...)`, you can usually just iterate directly over things.
7. If you want to print blank lines or something else after the help for each method, simply `print('\n\n')`.
8. `help(method)` does not work because for example if `method` is `'clear'` then that will be `help('clear')` and since there is no builtin function simply called `clear` that doesn't give anything. In other words you want the help for `phoneBook.clear`, not just `clear` by itself. To dynamically get `phoneBook.<method name here>` you use `getattr(phoneBook, method)`.

Comment: +1 for those suggestions. I am a novice programmer, as you can tell. It is nice when people tell you what to improve, instead of just downvoting...

Answer (score 1):

You mean smth like this? This will indeed print all non-dunder methods.

```
phoneBook = {"Joe":12, "Jason":13, "Johnny":14}

for method in dir(phoneBook):
    if "__" not in method:
        print(help(getattr(phoneBook, method)) + "\n\n")
```

From your title getting attribute from string is `getattr(your_object, your_method_str)`

But actually when you will try to `help(getattr(phoneBook, method)) + "\n\n"` you will get `TypeError` since `help` don't return a thing. So you need to handle it accordingly, maybe just with `help(getattr(phoneBook, method_name))` as [@Alex Hall said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49206439/3124746)

**UPDATE:**
if you want to use custom formatting of method description you can use `.__doc__`

```
print(getattr(phoneBook, method).__doc__, end='\n\n')
```